# Conversion from Infix to Postfix

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stack, queue

I want to write a program to read the input (infix expression) into a `Queue<char>` object. The output should be the postfix expression. I am confused while taking values from queue to stack.

This is my logic:

```
Stack<char> opStack;
Queue<char> postQ, infixQ;
// infixQ contains the infix expression to be converted.
// postQ contains the converted postfix expression.
char t;
while (infixQ is not empty) {
    t = infixQ.Front();
    infix.DeQueue();
    if (t is a number token) // (1)
        postQ.EnQueue(t);
    else if (opStack.IsEmpty()) // (2)
        opStack.Push(t);
    else if (t is a left paren token) // (3)
        opStack.Push(t);
    else if (t is a right paren token) { // (4)
        while (opStack.Top() is not a left paren) {
            postQ.EnQueue(opStack.Top());
            opStack.Pop();
        }
        opStack.Pop(); // discard a left paren from stack
    }
    else { // (5)
        while ( opStack is not empty and opStack.Top() != ’(’ and precedence of t <= precedence of opStack.Top()) {
            postQ.EnQueue(opStack.Top());
            opStack.Pop();
        }
        opStack.Push(t);
    }
}
// Now there are no tokens left in infixQ, so transfer remaining operators.
while (!opStack.IsEmpty()) { // (6)
    postQ.EnQueue(opStack.Top());
    opStack.Pop();
}
```

Comment: Where exactly lies the problem you need help with? The "Shunting-yard" algorithm is pretty straight-forward, you can find it even on the wikipedia. You can find help here but you need to precise your problem.